# Exclude @SpringBootApplication class for unit testing with @RestClientTest

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, spring-test, junit5

I have a simple service class that uses `RestTemplate`. I am testing it with `@RestClientTest` and expecting to initialize only required service bean

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication {
    @Bean fun restTemplate() = RestTemplateBuilder().build()

    @Bean fun xyzService() = XyzService()
}

@Service
class MyServiceImpl(private val restTemplate: RestTemplate): MyService {
    override fun fetch(id: String) {
        print(restTemplate.getForObject(URI("http://localhost:9090"), String::class.java))
    }
}

@RestClientTest(MyServiceImpl::class)
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockServer: MockRestServiceServer
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var myService: MyService

    @Test
    fun test(){
        mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(URI("http://localhost:9090")))
            .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body("hello world"))

        myService.fetch("123")

    }
}
```

I want to exclude the `DemoApplication` from being initialized in the test, only beans of service classes to be tested. Problem is that the bean initialization of `xyzService` fails (it has dependency on RabbitTemplate), and I don't want to mess up the test code with mocks.

Answer (score 0):

@RestClientTest won't be able to correctly filter out the components that are defined in your @SpringBootApplication-class (the same goes for configuration annotations like @EnableJpaRepositories defined on the main class). Move your beans to some other class annotated with @Configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication { }

@Configuration
class BeansConfig{
    @Bean fun restTemplate() = RestTemplateBuilder().build()

    @Bean fun xyzService() = XyzService()
}
```

According to Spring-Boot's documentation:

> If you use a test annotation to test a more specific slice of your
> application, you should avoid adding configuration settings that are
> specific to a particular area on the main method’s application class.
>
> The underlying component scan configuration of @SpringBootApplication
> defines exclude filters that are used to make sure slicing works as
> expected. If you are using an explicit @ComponentScan directive on
> your @SpringBootApplication-annotated class, be aware that those
> filters will be disabled. If you are using slicing, you should define
> them again.